State updating itself when focusing TextField - Flutter
I am trying to make a screen with filter, and a search buttons, but whenever i select a text field the screen start searching, even if i haven't written anything yet, i am using a column with 2 textFields, none of them uses onChanged or onTap functions, after the textfields, there is a button, where i wanted to do the search, and after the button there's a future builder, where the info is suposed to show.
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: TextFormField(
    controller: ctrl1,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      labelText: 'filter1',
      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
    ),
  ),
),
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: TextFormField(
    controller: ctrl2,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      labelText: 'filter2',
      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
    ),
  ),
)

Whenever i tap or change any of the text fields, apparently the state updates, forcing the search. How can i stop the textfields from updating the state of the Screen when tapped or changed?

Can you try using focusNode and adding a listener

Show Your screen code, you need to set textformfield Above the searching function

I resolved the issue by using this variable Future<List<dynamic>?>? infoList; as the future in FutureBuilder, and when the search button is pressed, i just update this var with the search function like this infoList = search(filter1.text, filter2.text);.
class _WidgSttflState extends State<WidgSttfl> {
  TextEditingController ctrl1 = TextEditingController(),
      ctrl2 = TextEditingController();
  PageController _pgView = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  ExpansionTileController exp = ExpansionTileController();
  Future<List<dynamic>?>? infoList;

  Future<dynamic> buildData(filter1, filter2) async {
    ...
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>?> search(filter1, filter2) async {
    return await buildData(filter1, filter2);
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    infoList = Future.value([]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: 'title'
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pgView,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          ...,
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Theme(
                data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                  dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: const Text('Filters'),
                  controller: exp,
                  initiallyExpanded: true,
                  leading: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => _pgView.previousPage(
                          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                          curve: Curves.easeInOutCubicEmphasized,
                        ),
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back,
                          color: Colors.orange,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const VerticalDivider(
                        thickness: 1,
                        indent: 5,
                        endIndent: 5,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  trailing: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt),
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: ctrl1,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          labelText: 'filter1',
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: ctrl2,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          labelText: 'filter2',
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ...,
                    SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              infoList = search(filter1.text, filter2.text);
                              exp.collapse();
                            });
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            'Search',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Divider(thickness: 2),
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: infoList,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      if (snapshot.data.isNotEmpty) {
                        return ListView.separated(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                              const Divider(),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(''),
                              subtitle: Text(''),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class _WidgSttflState extends State<WidgSttfl> {
  TextEditingController ctrl1 = TextEditingController(),
      ctrl2 = TextEditingController();
  PageController _pgView = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  ExpansionTileController exp = ExpansionTileController();

  Future<dynamic> buildData(filter1, filter2) async {
    ...
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>?> search(filter1, filter2) async {
    return await buildData(filter1, filter2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: 'title'
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pgView,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          ...,
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Theme(
                data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                  dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: const Text('Filters'),
                  controller: exp,
                  initiallyExpanded: true,
                  leading: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => _pgView.previousPage(
                          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                          curve: Curves.easeInOutCubicEmphasized,
                        ),
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back,
                          color: Colors.orange,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const VerticalDivider(
                        thickness: 1,
                        indent: 5,
                        endIndent: 5,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  trailing: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt),
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: ctrl1,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          labelText: 'filter1',
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: ctrl2,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          labelText: 'filter2',
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ...,
                    SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              search(filter1.text, filter2.text);
                              exp.collapse();
                            });
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            'Search',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Divider(thickness: 2),
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: search(ctrl1.text, ctrl2.text),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      if (snapshot.data.isNotEmpty) {
                        return ListView.separated(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                              const Divider(),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(''),
                              subtitle: Text(''),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


child: FutureBuilder(
future: search(ctrl1.text, ctrl2.text),
This is the reason. search function call automatically from here.
Try to use ValueListenableBuilder with ValueNotifier .

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Try this code.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class WidgSttfl extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgSttfl({super.key});

  @override
  State<WidgSttfl> createState() => _WidgSttflState();
}

class _WidgSttflState extends State<WidgSttfl> {
  TextEditingController ctrl1 = TextEditingController(),
      ctrl2 = TextEditingController();
  PageController _pgView = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  ExpansionTileController exp = ExpansionTileController();

  ValueNotifier<List<dynamic>?> resultNotifier = ValueNotifier(null); // pass null or [] as your requrement.

  Future<List<dynamic>> buildData(filter1, filter2) async {
    // do you calculations....
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>?> search(filter1, filter2) async {
    resultNotifier.value = null; // If you want to show loading pass null
    resultNotifier.value = await buildData(filter1, filter2);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    ctrl1.dispose();
    ctrl2.dispose();
    _pgView.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('title')),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pgView,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Theme(
                data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                  dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: const Text('Filters'),
                  controller: exp,
                  initiallyExpanded: true,
                  leading: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => _pgView.previousPage(
                          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                          curve: Curves.easeInOutCubicEmphasized,
                        ),
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back,
                          color: Colors.orange,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const VerticalDivider(
                        thickness: 1,
                        indent: 5,
                        endIndent: 5,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  trailing: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt),
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: ctrl1,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          labelText: 'filter1',
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: ctrl2,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          labelText: 'filter2',
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // Don't need to call setstate for show list
                            search(ctrl1.text, ctrl1.text);
                            exp.collapse();
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            'Search',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Divider(thickness: 2),
              Expanded(
                child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                  valueListenable: resultNotifier,
                  builder: (context, data, _) {
                    if (data == null) {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    } else if (data.isNotEmpty) {
                      return ListView.separated(
                        itemCount: data.length,
                        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(''),
                            subtitle: Text(''),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }

                    return Text("No record found !");
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Actually, that is my problem, i want to only allow the search by using the search button, but everytime i tap or change anything in the textfields, it triggers the search function.
